# REST API and consecutive calls dealing with huge data

Tags: java, rest

If I fire a rest request and it brings huge data but before it brings all data into memory then I fire another rest request of different endpoint.

Will old request data be washed from memory or both request will continue running in background?

Comment: hello, @witswickey welcome to StackOverflow. Will you be more specific in asking your question. The exact scenario would be the Set up you are using for e.g. you can specify the ORM tool name you are using and the other details which helps in getting you a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

Both requests will continue working independently because HTTP protocol is stateless, no two requests are connected to each other, each of them has separate identity and information to hold.

So, your second request will *not* impact your first request's execution unless it intentionally perform some destruction to the data which first request is looking for.

Answer (score 0):

**No**, old request data will not be lost unless you are using some **shared resource** like **static** variables or **Singleton** Object (where each field data will be overwritten by new request), For e.g `public static List<DbRecordsObject>` data storage will be lost partially or fully by new request if its common storage for both endpoints in your case.

Else both request will continue working independently on two separate **Threads** which can run parallel.